# how to get the particular index in a string if String contains a url in java

Tags: java, string

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_lastindexof.htm
I wanted to know the last index of java in that particular url. How can i get that?

Comment: using the lastindexof() method?

Comment: lastIndexOf method is used to find the last occurence of particular string. i want index 36 as answer but it will give me 32.

Comment: @Shuchita that is not clear from the current phrasing of your question. Please, rephrase it to be clearer. Sorry if you  took my previous comment as irony, it wasn't.

Answer (score 2):

`lastIndexOf()` returns the *beginning* of the char sequence, i.e., the index of the first character in that char sequence.

What you need, based on your comment, is :

```
String java = "java";
int index = url.lastIndexOf(java)+java.length();
```

assuming that you want the index in the `url` of the last character of this string.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Java String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

To know postion of last letter of java use [last index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String)) plus `"java".length`:

```
String url = "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_lastindexof.htm";
int lastIndex = url.lastIndexOf("java") + "java".length;
```

Answer (score 0):

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_lastindexof.htm";
    String substr = "java";

    System.out.println(url.lastIndexOf( substr ));
}
```

}

Comment: it will give you answer 32 not 36

Comment: It wil result in 35 actually

Answer (score 0):

Well I modified the program for your ease and used your string. It starts counting from zero(check result for "http") and answer is 35 for "java"

The word "java comes twice in the string. So lastIndexOf will return the position of the first char "j" in "java" of the last instance of "java"(which is second in this case) in the string.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String Str = new String("http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_lastindexof.htm");
      String SubStr1 = new String("Tutorials" );
      String SubStr2 = new String("Sutorials" );

      System.out.print("Found Last Index :" );
      System.out.println(Str.lastIndexOf("java" ));
      System.out.print("Found Last Index :" );
      System.out.println(Str.lastIndexOf( "http" ));
      System.out.print("Found Last Index :" );
      System.out.println( Str.lastIndexOf( SubStr1 ));
      System.out.print("Found Last Index :" );
      System.out.println( Str.lastIndexOf( SubStr1, 15 ));
      System.out.print("Found Last Index :" );
      System.out.println(Str.lastIndexOf( SubStr2 ));
   }
}

Output

Found Last Index :35
Found Last Index :0
Found Last Index :-1
Found Last Index :-1
Found Last Index :-1
```